# Why I get this error EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Tags: swift, exc-bad-instruction

Can anyone help me please and tell me why do I get error on line 2?
message box also says:

> SignIn
>   fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>   (lldb)

```
@IBAction func done(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    if isSignIn == false {

        //Register code

        //Checking for empty boxes

        if self.username.text == "" || self.password.text == "" || self.riderDriverSelect.selectedSegmentIndex == -1 {

            //Red Border color for missing fields


            if self.username.text == "" {
                self.username.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
                self.username.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
            }

            if self.password.text == "" {
                self.password.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
                self.password.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
            }

            if self.riderDriverSelect.selectedSegmentIndex == -1 {
                self.riderDriverSelect.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
                self.riderDriverSelect.layer.borderWidth = 1.0

                self.showAlert("Missing field required", message: "Fill in or select missing fields in red")
            }


        }else{
```

Comment: I don't see any unwrapped optional in your code, can you see in our stack trace and see if the error is reflected before?. In what line exactly is your error?

Answer (score 1):

had 1 string two bool, and both of the bool were ! had to change isSignIn Bool? that fixed the problem

var buttonTitlePressed: String?
    var isSignIn: Bool?
    var isUser: Bool!